# Kotlin - Extension Boolean property that returns true and then false (and so on)

Tags: kotlin, oop, extension-methods, getter-setter

I want an object to have a boolean property that returns true when I first get it, and the false, in a second time I get it. This must repeat every time I call it (if it is an even call, returns true; if it's an odd call, returns false).

I know I can achieve this in a class property like this:

```kotlin
class Foo {
    var bar: Boolean = true
        get() {
            val value = field
            bar = value.not()
            return value
        }
        private set
}
```

Test this snippet at: [kotlinlang Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/Uqh8WuIOo?theme=darcula)

However, an extension property can't be implemented in the same way, like this:

```kotlin
var Foo.bar: Boolean = true // I get the first error here
    get() {
        val value = field // I get the second error here
        bar = value.not()
        return value
    }
    private set
```

Because I get two erros:

##### 1: I can't initialize the variable

`extension property cannot be initialized because it has no backing field`

##### 2: I can't have access to the field variable

`Unresolved reference field`

Is it possible to achieve what I want with kotlin?

BTW, I'm using the version 1.8.0 of the kotlin library on Android.

Comment: It's possible, you just have to store the value in another place.

Comment: @Jorn, but doing so robustly so each instance of Foo's property is treated independently would be convoluted.

Comment: I'd love to know why you even want / need to do this. There's probably a better solution for whatever you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: You can in theory hack together some workaround like @broot suggested. But I'd never do anything like this in production code. Performance and concurrency issues aside, extension properties with state per object violate the *principle of least astonishment*. No one would reasonably expect that kind of behavior. Let alone that no one would reasonably expect getters to mutate state, worse yet, in a non-idempotent manner. Hacks like this will only get you an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: @dominicoder I thought that implementing something like I mentioned would simplify adding masks to an EditText (a text input UI element) on Android, because all I had to do is to use this property and check if I should apply the mask or not. But now I see that it would only save me a couple of lines of code... But it was cool seeing what you can do, like broot suggested and your comments. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to store the state somewhere. You could do so in a global map, as shown by @broot. See their excellent answer for some more details on why a global map might not be a good idea.

Implementation wise though, it might be nicer to hide the map in a property class:

```
fun main() {
    val one = Foo()
    val two = Foo()
    println(one.bar) // false
    println(two.bar) // false
    println(one.bar) // true
    println(one.bar) // false
    println(two.bar) // true
    println(one.bar) // true
}

class Foo

val Foo.bar by Alternate()

class Alternate {
    private val values = mutableMapOf<Foo, Boolean>()
    
    operator fun getValue(foo: Foo, p: KProperty<*>): Boolean {
        val previous = values[foo] ?: true
        values[foo] = !previous
        return !previous
    }
}
```

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/2rwvdwLjd)

Comment: Wow!!! Living and learning :D Nice implementation man Thanks for taking the time to help. I only have one question: What makes the `Alternate` class a "singleton"? I thougt that every `bar` from every `Foo` would have an instance of an `Alternate` and that the implementation on the `Alternate` class could have simply a boolean. I see I still have a lot to learn about kotlin.

Comment: The statement `val Foo.bar by Alternate()` creates a *single* `Alternate` instance that handles the property for every `Foo` instance. If you'd declare a second `val Foo.baz by Alternate()`, that would be its own `Alternate` instance with its own map.

Comment: Alternatively, you could declare `Alternate` as `object` instead of `class`, but then you'd have to key the map on the `property` parameter as well as the `foo` instance, to make sure each property alternates individually.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible without using some dirty tricks. The reason is that we need to store additional state per object, but we can't store any state using an extension. To store anything within object, we need a member.

One workaround is to keep a global map and store additional state there:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val f1 = Foo()
    val f2 = Foo()

    println(f1.bar) // true
    println(f1.bar) // false
    println(f1.bar) // true
    println(f1.bar) // false

    println(f1.bar) // true
    println(f2.bar) // true
    println(f1.bar) // false
    println(f2.bar) // false
    println(f1.bar) // true
    println(f2.bar) // true
}


class Foo

private val fooBarMap = WeakHashMap<Foo, Boolean>()

val Foo.bar: Boolean get() =
    fooBarMap.getOrDefault(this, true)
        .also { fooBarMap[this] = !it }
```

You can test this snippet at: [Kotlinlang](https://pl.kotl.in/RqkbshfXI)

This workaround has many drawbacks. Access to the "property" is much slower than to a real member. Above implementation is not thread safe and not only per-object, but per all `Foo` objects. We can easily synchronize access to the map, but then we will synchronize on all instances of `Foo`.

Also, it works properly only if the class doesn't implement custom `equals()`, so it uses a default identity check. If it implemented a custom logic for equality, `bar` will be partially shared between equal instances, but at the same time it may "reset" at a random time. We could fix this by using `IdentityHashMap` instead of `WeakHashMap`, but in this case the map will prevent `Foo` objects from being garbage collected. You can search in the internet for the implementation of map which is both weak and based on identity. It seems Guava has one: `MapMaker().weakKeys().makeMap()`.

Generally speaking, this should not be really considered a proper solution. This is a workaround and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Wow! That was a hell of an explanation. Thank you very much!! I see your points and I get now how this is not possible. But implementing something like I mentioned would simplify adding masks to an EditText (a text input UI element) on Android, because all I had to do is to use this property and check if I should apply a mask on the text or not.

Answer (score -1):

Extension properties can not have a backing field https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#companion-object-extensions

Thus you cannot store the current state of your property.